# How to insert text into an R function?

Tags: r, function, text, dynamic

Consider a function `f()` of a list of lists as follows:

```
out <- f(list_of_lists = list(list(a,1),list(a,2)))
```

I would like to call this function dynamically:

```
arg = "list(a,1),list(a,2)"
out <- f(list_of_lists = list(arg))
```

But that gives the error `"arg number 1 is not a list object"`.

How can I make `f()` read the object `arg` as the raw text it contains?

In Stata I would use macros to insert the text into the function; in R this is proving hard.

The question is inspired by an application of the `dataprep()` function in the `Synth` package, which has arguments with this type of complex formatting.

Comment: You may need to `parse` and `eval`uate.  If thee 'a' object is already defined `eval(parse(text = paste0("list(", arg, ")")))`

Comment: @akrun I tried parse and got the error " unexpected ',' " due to the nature of the text I'm working with here. Any tips?

Comment: The reason is that the string `"list(a,1),list(a,2)"` needs to be either inside a `list` or `c`.  For that purpose, you may need to `paste` as in the above comment updated.  Without knowing your function, it is not clear about what you are doing

Comment: @akrun That worked! Thank you. The lesson for me is that bits of text need to be turned into something that can be evaluated, then I can use the `eval(parse())` approach you suggest. If you care about getting credit please post as answer and I'll tag it as such. Really appreciate the quick insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `paste` with a `list` or `c` based on how whether we need a nested `list` or concatenate the `list` and then do the `eval`uation after `parse`ing

```
eval(parse(text = paste0("list(", arg, ")")))
```